# Is it possible to use and environment variable as docker healthy check

Tags: docker

I have a custom mysql image. When we run the container, it downloads a mysql dump from our artifactory to load some data. I have the following health check in my docker run command:

```
--health-cmd='mysql -u myusername -pMyPassword'
```

But what I want to do is to set the health of the container to healthy when the data has been imported, that usually takes around 5 min. One idea I had is maybe set an environment variable, but in that case, I wouldn't know what the health-cmd would be. Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

I am just starting with docker, my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Short answer, no. An environment variable would only be visible to the process that sets the variable and other child processes. The healthcheck is not run as a child process, but as a completely separate command in the same container namespace. You would need to write to a file or find another way to perform the healthcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to update a special table (say `status`) when the load is done. Then replace the health-check command with a `bash` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# the table status is updated when the load finishes
SQLSTMT="SELECT status FROM myDatabase.status WHERE status='done'"

# execute the SQL script and get the result
STATUS=`mysql -AN -e "${SQLSTMT}"`

# return exit code 0 (container healthy) if status is done,
# otherwise exit code 1 (container is not healthy)
[ "$STATUS" == 'done' ]
```

the `health-cmd` becomes:

```
--health-cmd='/path/to/script.sh'
```

It should work even if you create the table after the load process has ended.

**Another option** is to create a new file (even empty) when the loading has finished. The health command will test the presence of the file:

```
--health-cmd="/usr/bin/test -f /path/to/file"
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution with a healthy check:

--health-cmd="mysql -u user -pPASSWORD --database=mysql --execute='show databases;'"

Then I do a loop in a shell script waiting for the status to be healthy

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the `show databases` command. I think it succeeds (returns 0) as soon as the database is created but that doesn't mean all the data has been loaded. Well, I think it's a good enough solution.